# UITableViewCell: Custom Row Height for prototype cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, row-height

In my storyboard file I am designing multiple prototype cells in a UITableView. Each cell has its own unique Cell Identifier.

Depending on the section and the row I dequeue one of the prototype cells in method - tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

For most of the prototype cells I have not changed the Row Height. On my storyboard, their height seems to be determined by the property 'Row Height' under 'Size Inspector' of UITableView.

For one prototype cell I have changed the height through the property 'Row Height' under 'Size Inspector' of the specific UITableViewCell. The checkbox 'Custom' is also checked.

On my storyboard this seem to work well. But during runtime when my cells are being dequeued and added to the TableView, all cells get the default row height.

Now, I am aware of the method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: which is being mentioned in other posts but it seems a little odd to use as I am setting a custom row height in my storyboard already.

Does somebody know why this property is not working? Is this property maybe mend to be used in different situations?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called (for each row of the table) *before* the cells are displayed, i.e. before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. That is necessary to compute the layout of the underlying scrollview, the scroll indicators etc.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for clarifying the heightForRowAtIndexPath method. But this does not explain why this property is available if it is not being used.

Comment: @Brabbeldas: Hi! The height property is in fact used to create the cell. I have just verified that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a cell with the height specified in the Size Inspector. But the tableview does not use the cell's height for positioning the cells. It uses only the value from `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: do you mean that the property is only used in design-time?

Comment: No, the cells do really have the height that you specified. But the cells's height is not used for *positioning* the cell. So if the cell's height is larger than what `heightForRowAtIndexPath` returns, then the cell will overlap with the next cell.

Comment: Now that is a clear answer! I now do understand what you are saying! ..should I have been able to find this in the documentation?

Comment: That would be a separate question :-)

Comment: What you may be able to do is pre-fetch a few of you custom height cells before-hand, and return their height in the delegate methods... It would be really handy if storyboards could do the job itself...

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use Interface Builder in Xcode 5 to change the height of the rows in a table view without code you can do it in two places:

- Select the table view, show the **Size inspector** and type it in
  **Row Height**, in the **Table View Size** section.

[image: Default row height]

- Select the prototype cell, show the **Size inspector**, check **Custom** in the **Table View Size** section and type the row height in the associate text field.

[image: Custom row height]

Could it be that you're using the second method? Try to use the first method to set the default height of all the rows in the table view and the second to tell Interface Builder about the exceptions.

Comment: Row height can be set in many places. Where are you trying to set it?

Comment: I mean in Storyboard custom height for prototype cell is not working when I use dynamics prototype. From I know it's common know.